# Neither NPM nor GitBash are operational at the moment. How can that be solved?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, git-bash

I am new to GitBash and do not know how it functions within VisualStudio Code. The challenge that I am faced with is enabling React.js to operate within VSCode. As it stands, the error message below is what's being output at this time.

```
D:\_Dearest_Lord_God,_please_intuitively_reveal_the_things_that_used_to_baffle_me]\_Projects-React]\node_modules\babel-jest (version: 27.2.4)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "babel-jest" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if D:\_Dearest_Lord_God,_please_intuitively_reveal_the_things_that_used_to_baffle_me]\_Projects-React]\node_modules\babel-jest is outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls babel-jest in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed babel-jest.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! affiliate-marketing-project@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the affiliate-marketing-project@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Refined_Silver\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-12T16_55_33_704Z-debug.log
PS D:\_Dearest_Lord_God,_please_intuitively_reveal_the_things_that_used_to_baffle_me]\_Projects-React]\affiliate-marketing-project>
```

I followed the instructions above, but to no avail. For starters, "babel-jest" did not exist within the dependencies section of my package.json.
Below is the message that I have been receiving, which is inside of the debug log for React within Visual Studio Code.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.15
3 info using node@v14.18.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle affiliate-marketing-project@0.1.0~prestart: affiliate-marketing-project@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle affiliate-marketing-project@0.1.0~start: affiliate-marketing-project@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle affiliate-marketing-project@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle affiliate-marketing-project@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\_Dearest_Lord_God,_please_intuitively_reveal_the_things_that_used_to_baffle_me]\_Projects-React]\affiliate-marketing-project\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Python39\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Ruby26-x64\bin;C:\Users\Refined_Silver\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Refined_Silver\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\ProgramData\Refined_Silver\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\Refined_Silver\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Refined_Silver\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin
9 verbose lifecycle affiliate-marketing-project@0.1.0~start: CWD: D:\_Dearest_Lord_God,_please_intuitively_reveal_the_things_that_used_to_baffle_me]\_Projects-React]\affiliate-marketing-project
10 silly lifecycle affiliate-marketing-project@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle affiliate-marketing-project@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle affiliate-marketing-project@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: affiliate-marketing-project@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5)
14 verbose pkgid affiliate-marketing-project@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd D:\_Dearest_Lord_God,_please_intuitively_reveal_the_things_that_used_to_baffle_me]\_Projects-React]\affiliate-marketing-project
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19043
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v14.18.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.15
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error affiliate-marketing-project@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the affiliate-marketing-project@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I am not-at-all familiar with how to read what is happening within the NPM / GitBash start-up process. Everything was working fine until I installed GitBash. I would appreciate some assistance with how GitBash functions.

I would appreciate any insight as to how this can be solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed step 6 and removed `babel-jest` in `D:\_Dearest_Lord_God,_please_intuitively_reveal_the_things_that_used_to_baffle_me]\_Projects-React]\node_modules` ?

`react-scripts` comes with `babel-jest`. It warns you about the conflicting installation up the tree.

Comment: Thank you so much for viewing my concern. For whatever reason, babel-jest is not listed in the package.json file. At least not in the immediate react file that I am working on.

Comment: `Projects-React/affiliate-marketing-project/package.json` might not have a `babel-jest` entry but according to your log there is a `Projects-React/node_modules/babel-jest` package directory which is also considered for resolving that module.

Comment: Thanks, Philipp! I'm still stuck, but at least I learned where is babel-jest. I deleted that file and am still receiving the same error messages. What should I do now?